# ASP.NET Membership changing applicationName not reflecting on created user's application id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I have used ASP.NET membership in my ASP.NET MVC project. When configuring membership in my webconfig I had forgotten to mention `applicationName` in my config.

So by default when user were created by my site an applicationName `'/'` was added to the `aspnet_Applications` table.

[image]

Later I found [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers) by ScottGu where he has also said to set the "applicationName" property when configuring the Membership providers.

Now I added another entry to this `aspnet_Applications` table say 'Abc' and also added the `applicationName="Abc"` in my membership config. Now I expected all the users created hence forth to have ApplicationId of "Abc".

Still the old ApplicationId (of '/') only is getting used.

Can someone guide me on this please.

**Update:**

My config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15" hashAlgorithmType="CustomPbkdf2Hash">
  <providers>
    <clear />        
    <add name="CustomSqlMembershipProvider" type="Abc.Service.Services.SecurityService.CustomMembership.CustomSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="AbcAdManagementAspNetConnection" applicationName="Abc Web Application"  enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from SQL Server Stored Proc"  />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Show the `membership` config section of your web.config

Comment: @codingbiz have added the config section in my question now.

Comment: @Yasser did you get to fix this?

Comment: @WAQ are you getting the same problem now ?

Comment: @Yasser yes facing the same issue

Comment: I think my issue was a typo in the application name. Do you have applicationName attribute in your membership config @WAQ ?

Comment: i have three applications, all using same database. and all have there respective 'applicationname' attribute set (which is different for each application) in the web.config file. But still when i create user for each application, default '/' application name appears in the database for each user.